# How do I count the number of rows returned?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm using [My_model](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model) (developed by jamierumbelow) for my small application.

I've got a basic user search and I'm trying to paginate the results but I can't figure out how to get the total number of rows returned by the result. This is the code I have in my controller:

```
protected function get_users(){


$this->load->model('user_model');


$this->data["users"]  = $this->user_model;

if($this->input->post('country')){
    $this->data["users"] = $this->data["users"]->search('country', $this->input->post('country'));
}

if($this->input->post('city')){
    $this->data["users"] = $this->data["users"]->search('city', $this->input->post('city'));
}


if($this->input->post('forename')){
    $this->data["users"] = $this->data["users"]->search('forename', $this->input->post('forename'));
}


if($this->input->post('surname')){
    $this->data["users"] = $this->data["users"]->search('surname', $this->input->post('surname'));
}

$this->data["bla"]  = $this->data["users"]->get_all();

}
```

How do I figure out the total number of results? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->data["users"]->count_all()` for row count.

Comment: When I use $this->data["total"] =  $this->data["users"]->count_all(); all the rows are returned in my search. I'm sure I'm somehow modifying the $this->data["users"] when I call the count_all() method.